# OpenCV arrowedLine function

Tags: c++, opencv, drawing

I try to drow an arrowedLine on my image but i get an error.
Please take a look on my code:

```
point1 = Point(x, y);
vect.push_back(point1);
    for (int i = vect.size()-5; i>=0,i < vect.size() - 1; i++)
        {
         arrowedLine(cameraFeed,vect[i] , vect[i+1],Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0, 0.1);
        }
```

ERROR: arrowedLine is undefined
Which header should I include for this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `arrowedLine` is in:

- OpenCV 3.0: `imgproc.hpp`
- OpenCV 2.4.12, 2.4.11, 2.4.10 : `core.hpp`
- OpenCV <= 2.4.9 : not present.

You can avoid this kind of problems with the *include all*: `opencv.hpp`.

---

For OpenCV <= 2.4.9 you can write a custom function, based on OpenCV [arrowedLine](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp)

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that I have OCV 2.4.9 ,is there a similar function in OpenCV 2.4.9?

Comment: Or you can make your own function based on [arrowedLine](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp) implementation @MahagneySaleh

Comment: I made my own function.Thancks! @Miki